# Countdown timer increase on interaction?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, countdown

I have a form that I want to close after 5 seconds if no mouse interaction is done but if any mouse interaction is done I want it to close `countdown + 5 seconds` and each interaction would increase it by 5 seconds.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
int countdown = 5;
System.Timers.Timer timer;
```

Start timer

```
timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(ProcessTimerEvent);
timer.Start();
```

The event

```
private void ProcessTimerEvent(Object obj, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    --countdown;
    if (countdown == 0)
    {
        timer.Close();
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => { this.Close(); }));
    }
}
```

And just for testing I am using the form mouseclick event to increaes the countdown by 5 but will have to change it to a a different event because if you click on a label or any other control on the form it will not increase the timer.

```
private void NotifierTest_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    countdown += 5;
}
```

---

## Questions

- Am I implementing a countdown where
  the counter can be increased in a
  correct way ?
- Should I change anything ?
- How would you do this if any different from what I have done ?
- How should I handle the mouse click
  capture ?
- Using a Low Level Hook ?
- Using mouse click position and verify
  if it was or not on my winform ?

## Other option

A different option I am currently thinking is to capture if the mouse is within the form area or not and enable / disable the close countdown if it is not within the area but I am not sure on how to interact with the mouse for this hence the above questions about how would I interact with the mouse.

Comment: So if they click 10 times quickly you want the form to stay open for 50 seconds after they stopped clicking?  Not sure why you would want that.  I would be confused as a user unless there was some sort of progress bar that filled up more on every click and slowly drained over time.

Comment: @Justin that is what would happen, the above code currently does that, I do understand it is not very elegant but I am looking for options such as if the mouse if over the form. Well the user would not know about this, it is basicly something like if the notify comes up the user will look at it but he will only interact with it if there is something they liked or need or found interesting, something along those lines.

Comment: @Prix, rather than incrementing `countdown += 5` you can just reset it using `countdown = 5` that will reset it back to 5 seconds rather than accumulating on every mouse interaction.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're looking for code help or user interface design suggestions... As one possibly similar example, Microsoft Outlook's new e-mail notifications show up as a small box in the corner of the screen above the system tray, and fade out after a few seconds.  If you move your mouse over them, they stop fading out.  I think they will then stay up forever, but they have a close button (typical red 'X') to dismiss them.

Comment: @Justin that is what I am doing or trying to, initially they will fade out or go away in 5 seconds if the mouse is not over it or no interaction is done to it, I am currently reworking it to interact with the mouse but I am not very sure on how I should interact with the mouse, using the winforms events for the mouse doesnt cover the controls very well.

Comment: @Chris Taylor That was because I did not want it to throw away the few seconds left but increase on top of it, but using the mouse over event I might just do that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in essence what you are doing is fine, the real trick is going to be to handle the mouse events.

Here is a quick and dirty example of how you could do this just checking if the mouse is in the client area of the window. Basically on every timer expiry the code gets the mouse position on the screen and checks if that overlaps with the client area of the window. You should probably also check if the window is active etc. but this should be a reasonable starting point.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Timers;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WinFormsAutoClose
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    int _countDown = 5;
    System.Timers.Timer _timer;

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
      _timer.AutoReset = true;
      _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ProcessTimerEvent);
      _timer.Start();
    }

    private void ProcessTimerEvent(Object obj, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) 
    {
      Invoke(new Action(() => { ProcessTimerEventMarshaled(); }));
    }

    private void ProcessTimerEventMarshaled()
    {
      if (!IsMouseInWindow())
      {
        --_countDown;
        if (_countDown == 0)
        {
          _timer.Close();
          this.Close();
        }
      }
      else
      {
        _countDown = 5;
      }
    }

    private bool IsMouseInWindow()
    {
      Point clientPoint = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
      return ClientRectangle.Contains(clientPoint);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: partially that is what I am currently trying to do but instead of doing a timer event I am trying to make a Mouse Over event that will start or not the countdown timer based on if the mouse is within the form or not but using the winforms options when I move the mouse out of it, it will not catch the event so I am guessing I will have to capture the mouse else where am I correct ?

Comment: @Prix, using the MouseOver, MouseEnter, MouseLeave events can be problematic if there are other controls on the form because those controls will swallow the mouse events before the form gets them under certain circumstances. That is why I opted to brute force check the mouse position relative to the form on the screen which is totally independent of the controls on the form.

Comment: yes my bad I just noticed it now, works like a charm really appreciated your time and help.