# Countdown timer increase on user interaction

Tags: javascript, concurrency

Consider this C# question: [Countdown timer increase on interaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778686/countdown-timer-increase-on-interaction)

I am in need of an equivalent for Javascript. That is, the following:

## Problem

I need a callback to be called after some time T however if user interaction happens before the callback is executed then this time T must be increased by some number X. How is this modelled using Javascript?

## Background (the why)

I have a page forward button which upon being clicked increases the page by 1. Increasing the page causes some hefty computations to happen so it'd be preferable to only switch page after some small time frame so that a user that's spamming the page button won't make the programs perf. go in the bin.

Comment: Is the increase number X a constant or it's calculated somehow?

Comment: I'd probably just want to reset the timer to the original T (so if it starts at 20ms, drops to 15 I'd like to reset it to 20). In other words: Yes, a trivial calculation happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can simply clear the timeout and set it again.

```
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(function(){}, 1000);
```

I made a quick codepen with an example. I hope it helps: https://codepen.io/daniti/pen/gjePdo

Answer (score 1):

You can use a debounce function. It sets a timer and if an interation happens before timer expiration it deletes the old timer and creates a new one, effectively resets the time. Example:

`function debounce(fn, delay) {
    let timerId;
    return function (...args) {
        if (timerId)
            clearTimeout(timerId);
        timerId = setTimeout(() => {
            fn(...args);
            timerId = null;
        }, delay);
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timeout : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

```js
document.getElementById("spamMe").onclick = doLongAction;

var canDoLongAction = true;
var timeout;

function doLongAction() {
  if (canDoLongAction) {
    // prevent relaunch of action
    canDoLongAction = false
    
    // the action will become available in 2sec
    timeout = window.setTimeout(
      () => {canDoLongAction = true}, 
      2000
    )
    
    // you do your long action
    alert("hey")
  } else {
  
    // if clicked while the timeout is going reset it
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = window.setTimeout(
      () => {canDoLongAction = true}, 
      2000
    )
    
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="spamMe">spam me!!</button>
```

in the example, the button is blocked until you stop clicking for 2 seconds